# count the duplicate and return all the field removing the duplicate in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've got problem on including the field after counting its duplicate

my response from api is like this:

```
items: [
  {
    id: 1
    item: {
      id: 27,
      product_id_number: "123", 
      type: "Equipment", 
      name: "Item1"
    }
    item_id: 27
    serial_no: null
    stock_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2
    item: {
      id: 27,
      product_id_number: "123", 
      type: "Equipment", 
      name: "Item1"
    }
    item_id: 27
    serial_no: null
    stock_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3
    item: {
      id: 28,
      product_id_number: "123", 
      type: "Non-Equipment", 
      name: "Item2"
    }
    item_id: 28
    serial_no: null
    stock_id: 1
  },
]
```

I tried using from this [JavaScript - Count and remove duplicates from array of objects ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60767563/javascript-count-and-remove-duplicates-from-array-of-objects-es6)

```
const unique = {};
for (const item of items) {
  if (unique[item.itemId] === undefined) {
    unique[item.itemId] = 1;
  } else {
    unique[item.itemId] += 1;
  }
}

const newArr = [];
for (const key in unique) {
  const newObj = {
    quantity: unique[key],
    itemId: key,
  };
  newArr.push(newObj);
}
```

and only give me

```
newArr: [
 {
  itemId: "27"
  quantity: 2
 },
 {
  itemId: "28"
  quantity: 1
 }
]
```

Is there anyway on including every fields on the items on the newArr with also have a another field of counting its duplicate item_id like this?

```
newArr: [
 {
  itemId: "27"
  quantity: 2,
  item: {
      id: 27,
      product_id_number: "123", 
      type: "Equipment", 
      name: "Item1"
    },
   serial_no: null
   stock_id: 1
 },
 {
  itemId: "28"
  quantity: 1
  item: {
      id: 28,
      product_id_number: "123", 
      type: "Non-Equipment", 
      name: "Item2"
    },
   serial_no: null
   stock_id: 1
 }
]
```

Would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You generate the `unique` object just fine, but the item element mapping misses including the item properties. You *could* search the `item` array each time, but that is wasteful.

```
const newArr = [];
for (const key in unique) {
  const newObj = {
    quantity: unique[key],
    itemId: key, // <-- need entire item object
  };
  newArr.push(newObj);
}
```

## Solution

Copy the item properties earlier while generating the `unique` object.

Create an object mapping of your unique items with an injected `quantity` property.

```
items.reduce((unique, item) => {
  if (!unique[item.item_id]) {
    // unique element doesn't exist, create one and spread item in
    unique[item.item_id] = {
      quantity: 0,
      ...item,
    };
  } 
  unique[item.item_id].quantity += 1; // update quantity of existing
  return unique;
}, {})
```

Then use `Object.values` on the result to return an array of the values from the object map.

```js
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    item: {
      id: 27,
      product_id_number: "123", 
      type: "Equipment", 
      name: "Item1"
    },
    item_id: 27,
    serial_no: null,
    stock_id: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    item: {
      id: 27,
      product_id_number: "123", 
      type: "Equipment", 
      name: "Item1"
    },
    item_id: 27,
    serial_no: null,
    stock_id: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    item: {
      id: 28,
      product_id_number: "123", 
      type: "Non-Equipment", 
      name: "Item2"
    },
    item_id: 28,
    serial_no: null,
    stock_id: 1,
  },
];

const unique = Object.values(
  items.reduce((unique, item) => {
    if (!unique[item.item_id]) {
      unique[item.item_id] = {
        quantity: 0,
        ...item,
      };
    } 
    unique[item.item_id].quantity += 1;
    return unique;
  }, {})
);

console.log(unique);
```